# DRF serializer.save() not saving to database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have an api that will do a patch on a resource (MyUser). It validates ok and seems to save the object, however when querying the database the changes have not been saved.

```
class UserSignupView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
  serializer_class = MyUserSerializer

  def get_object(self, email):
    obj = MyUser.objects.get(email=email)
    self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
    return obj

  def patch(self, request):
    print(request.user)
    user = self.get_object(request.user.email)
    print(user.street)
    serializer = MyUserSerializer(user, data=request.data, partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    savedUser = MyUser.objects.get(email=request.user.email)
    print(savedUser.street)
    print(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data)


class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = MyUser
    fields = (
        'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'street', 'locality', 'city',
        'county', 'postcode')
```

Looking at the print statements I get:
user@example.com
None
123 Fake Street
MyUser object

It returns the correct serialised data which contains the changes but the database does not have the changes.  The database connection is ok as I can query it and make other reads/writes/etc.  It's pretty much the same as the UpdateModelMixin except I've had to override the get_object with a passed in parameter.

Comment: Since `print(savedUser.street)` prints the street correctly, your data is saved to the database. Where do you see that the object isn't saved?

Comment: When I look at the actual database.  The data just isn't there

Comment: That's not possible, you're looking in a wrong way. `MyUser.objects.get(email=request.user.email)` gives you a fresh object fetched from the database.

Comment: I know, this is why I'm confused.  I'm looking at the django admin page and at the actual database and they are both missing the value for street that gets printed out

Comment: How is `MyUser` defined? And are you looking at the Django `User` or at `MyUser`?

Comment: I think there is something in the sequence of events.  We've defined a hook for our authentication (in settings DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES) which creates the user, it calls MyUser.objects.get_or_create(email) adds a couple more things then calls user.save().  Then it gets to the api code where it does the code defined above.  Is there some sort of weird thing happening where you can't save the object again?

Comment: Again, I’d like to see the MyUser model. How does it relate to django.contrib.auth?

Comment: Could be that the MyUser object is saved after you’ve run the patch() method with a different copy of the object.

Comment: class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    street = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    locality = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    county = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=255)
    postcode = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=8)

Comment: how can you ensure the correct object is saved at the right time?

Comment: I don’t understand how the user is created in the first place and how the `patch()` method is called

Comment: Set a breakpoint in both your custom auth hook and your patch method and check the sequence of events

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the update method and see what happens:

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = (
            'id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'street', 'locality', 'city',
            'county', 'postcode')

       def update(self, instance, validated_data):       
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name',instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name',instance.last_name)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email',instance.email)
        instance.phone_number = validated_data.get('phone_number',instance.phone_number)
        instance.street = validated_data.get('street',instance.street)
        instance.locality = validated_data.get('locality',instance.locality)
        instance.city = validated_data.get('city',instance.city)
        instance.county = validated_data.get('county',instance.county)
        instance.postcode = validated_data.get('postcode',instance.postcode)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```