# SerDe problem with django rest framework and foreign key

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**Context:**

I have written a simple django rest framework app as BE and a react JS app as FE. The db is SQLite and it's gonna stay that way, since there are only 2 simple models and the number of users will be quite limited as well.
For the sake of the example let's assume there is only one team currently with `name="First"` and `id=1`.

Requirements:

1. display in a table the list of players with team as a name, not its id.
2. add players from form

Code:

**models.py**

```py
class Player(models.Model):
    first_name = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

**views.py**

```py
class PlayersView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = PlayerSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In order to meed 1st requirement I've implemented serializer like this:

**serializers.py**

```py
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = serializers.CharField(source="team.name", read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = "__all__"
```

That worked fine, but I wasn't able to add the players to the database when processing the request from the FE.

The body of that POST request is:

**body**

```
{
"first_name": "John",
"last_name": "Doe",
"team": 1
}
```

Looking on SO I found:

- [Retrieving a Foreign Key value with django-rest-framework serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280007/retrieving-a-foreign-key-value-with-django-rest-framework-serializers)
- [How to serialize the foreign key field in django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68743630/how-to-serialize-the-foreign-key-field-in-django-rest-framework)
- [DRF serializer.save() not saving to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53263981/drf-serializer-save-not-saving-to-database)

I tried sending the request body as (the FE has full info on team, both name and id, that part is working fine):

**body**

```
{
"first_name": "John",
"last_name": "Doe",
"team": "First"
}
```

But that was a dead end.

I played with serializer and tried:
**serializers.py**

```py
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="team.name", queryset=Team.objects.all())
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data["team"] = validated_data["team"]["name"] # Since the Player initializer expected team to be an instance of Team and not a str/name neither an int/id
        return Player(**validated_data)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        r ={
         "id": instance.id,
         "first_name": instance.first_name,
         "last_name": instance.last_namem
         "team": instance.team.name if instance.team else ""
         }
        return r
    
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = "__all__"
```

The above does not raise any exceptions, but it doesn't save the new entry into db neither. When I logged the `serializer.data` after validation the `id` of the new item was `None`.
I'd appreciate if somebody could either tell me where the mistake is and/or point me towards a good solution of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not then use a nested serializer to represent the team?

```py
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = "__all__"

class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = TeamSerializer(queryset=Team.objects.all())
    
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = "__all__"
```

That will give you something like

```json
{
"first_name": "John",
"last_name": "Doe",
"team": {
 "id": 1,
 "name": "First"
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If there is a relationship between team and player, you should use the a [serializer that represents the relationship](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations).

```py
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    team = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: I did, please take a look at the attempt I described (the 2nd `serializers.py`, below links to questions I browsed before)

Comment: Also this doesn't work, needs to have queryset argument problvided, but even then the team is displayed as number, not the name (when fetching players and not teams)